# Update hosts within fabric script

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to loop over all my server configurations in fabric and get their hostname like such:

```
from fabric.api import env, run

def serv_foo():
    env.hosts = ['bla@example.com']

def serv_bar():
    env.hosts = ['bla@example2.com']

def get_all_servers():
    return {(k,v) for k,v in globals().items() if k.startswith("serv_")}

def get_hostnames():
    for serv_name, serv_fptr in get_all_servers():
        print(env.hosts)
        serv_fptr()
        print(env.hosts)
        hostname = run("hostname")
        print(hostname)
```

This however fails:

```
>>> fab get_hostnames

>>> []
>>> ['bla@example.com']
>>> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

How can I dynamically update the hosts in fabric?

- NOTE1: I am aware that the default call would be `fab serv_foo get_hostnames`. Not interested in that.
- NOTE2: `execute(serv_fptr)` gives the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a host for the `run` command by using [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute):

```
from fabric.api import env, run
from fabric.tasks import execute


def serv_foo():
    return ['bla@example.com']


def serv_bar():
    return ['bla@example2.com']


def get_all_servers():
    return {(k, v) for k, v in globals().items() if k.startswith("serv_")}


def get_hostname():
    return run("hostname")


def get_hostnames():
    for serv_name, serv_fptr in get_all_servers():
        print(env.hosts)
        hostname = execute(get_hostname, hosts=serv_fptr())
        print(hostname)
```

or [settings](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings) context manager:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.context_managers import settings


def serv_foo():
    return 'bla@example.com'


def serv_bar():
    return 'bla@example2.com'


def get_all_servers():
    return {(k, v) for k, v in globals().items() if k.startswith("serv_")}


def get_hostnames():
    for serv_name, serv_fptr in get_all_servers():
        with settings(host_string=serv_fptr()):
            hostname = run("hostname")
            print(hostname)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: First answer runs like a charm. Second gives the same host problem. Going with the first one since that can also generically run any function. Thanks.